# Does installing resilient channel directly to the concrete ceiling reduce the effectiveness of soundproofing?

Tags: drywall, sound-proofing

My bedroom that is inside an apartment building. All of walls, ceiling and ground are made of reinforced concrete (concrete with steel).

This is from outside of my bedroom.

[image]

This is from inside of my bedroom.

[image]

For the purpose of soundproofing, I need to build a studwork and install drywall on the walls. how about ceiling? Does installing resilient channel directly to the concrete ceiling reduce the effectiveness of soundproofing? If yes. What kind of layers do I need to add between the concrete ceiling and resilient channel?

Note_1: I am aware that screws, glue could be used to install resilient channels to the ceiling, which is not what I am asking. I am asking for some consideration of soundproofing.

Note_2: I am pretty sure that reinforced concrete transmits sound, because I have been disturbed by the sound from upstairs through ceiling, and that's why I need to install resilient channel to soundproof my ceiling.

Comment: You need more sound proofing then the already very sound proof concrete bunker you have ?  http://www.buildwithmark.com/resilient_channel.html  Perhaps what you are really seeking is not sound proofing but Acoustic panels to create a space that does not echo so much. https://www.acousticalsurfaces.com/acoustical-panels/

Comment: @AlaskaMan Thanks for yor reminder. I am pretty sure I need soundproofing, since the noise from upstairs and outside continuously bother me.

Comment: Given all your questions you need to employ a professional.

Comment: Sound does not transmit through concrete walls very easily but sound inside of a room with concrete walls bounces around and is amplified.  So Acoustic panels  or even something as simple as some fabric hung on the walls will help considerably.

Comment: resilient channel brackets can connect directly to concrete using masonry achors like concrete nails or drive pins etc.

Comment: @SolarMike How do I identify if a person is a professional? Is there some kind of certificate for soundproof engineer?

Comment: @Jasen usually a resilient channel is attached to a wooden joist. would directly connecting to concrete ceiling affect the performance of soundproofing?

Comment: for some reason I was thinking of the channel with the plastic shock-absorber brackets,   resilient channel will need short screws for the drywall, or need to be spaced off the concrete a bit so that the screws don't bottom out.

Comment: Use screws, glue or double-sided sticky tape...

Comment: Is this a rental apartment?

Comment: How have you confirmed the walls and ceiling are concrete? From your pictures the walls could be plaster or drywall over wood or steel framing. Choosing a place that is inconspicuous, drill a small hole and see what is drilled out.

Comment: I agree with Jack the wall with door definitely does not look like a concrete wall nor do the others.

Comment: You do understand how decibels and sound attenuation works, and that soundproofing is misnamed: It will not nearly STOP sound, but only attenuate it somewhat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin - the obvious - if the disturbances are coming from above you need to soundproof the ceiling if it's also through the walls then you need to soundproof both ceiling and walls. Walls can be problematic because of window casings and outlets all of which will have to be modified or worked around.
You don't want to directly attach the resilient channel to the concrete. You will first need to attach furring strips (or studs) to the concrete and then the resilient channels perpendicular to the furring strips. For maximum effectiveness sound-absorbing mat should be installed between the furring strips. You can then attach the drywall to the resilient channel all of this while following mfr directions. The principle behind the resilient channel is that the channel minimizes the transfer of vibrations (i.e. sound) from the concrete wall to the drywall you install. This is why the mfr suggests that you don't attach the drywall at the studs or furring strips but at points between them. You can further improve effectiveness by adding additional layers of sound-absorbing mat, Celotex, Wonder Board, Duroc or some other sound-absorbing material between the furring strips and the drywall, once again, following the mfr recommendations. There are numerous options here that could result in a lot of expense and maybe overkill. It all depends on the amount of noise coming in, how sensitive you are to it, and how much you want to spend. If you haven't already you should review all of these options at: http://www.soundproofing.org/infopages/channel.htm.
You might want to consider starting simple by not adding extensive sound absorbing barriers until you see how the basic resilient channel set-up works and then adding sound absorbing tiles or other material to the surface of the drywall if you need it. It could end up being a little claustrophobic but there you go. Good Luck!